# How can I interpolate $z_t = x(1-t)+y t$ with single-precision floats so that it satisfies $x\leq z\leq y$, $z_0=x$, $z_1=y$?

Tags: numerical-analysis, floating-point

Given two (here and below: single-precision, IEEE 32-bit floats) normalized floating-point numbers $x, y$ (perhaps of reasonable range: my counterexamples don't have unusual magnitudes), and another floating-point number $0\leq t\leq 1$, I would like to evaluate the linear interpolant
$$ z_t = x(1-t) + yt $$
in such a way that:
$$ \begin{gathered}
x \leq z_t \leq y,\\
z_0 = x, \qquad z_1 = y,
\end{gathered} $$
as well as
$$ 
z_t \leq z_s \quad\text{whenever}\quad 0\leq t \leq s \leq 1. $$

The direct formula, $z_t = x(1-t)+yt$ fails. For example, with $x=2.0000076$, $y=2.9007149$, we have in single-precision arithmetic
$$ \mathrm{fl}(z_t) < x, \qquad \text{for}\quad2.9802326\times 10^{-8}\leq t<4.109652\times 10^{-8}. $$

The obvious other formula $z_t = x + (y-x)t$ satisfies $z_t \geq x$, but sometimes $z_1 > y$ for
$$ x=1.0000609, \quad y=3.9999998, \quad z_1 = 4.0. $$

I considered
$$ z_t = \mathrm{fma}(x, 1-t, y t), $$
and it has counterexamples `x=y=1.9210567f0, t=0.10707888f0, z_t = 1.9210566f0 < x` and `x=-1.4928777f-36, y=-1.4825014f-36, t=2.9802322f-8, z_t=-1.4928778f-36 < x`.

If I allow using if-statements, then simply evaluating one of
$$ x+(y-x)t\quad(t\leq\tfrac12), \qquad y - (y-x)(1-t)\quad(t\geq\tfrac12) $$
works as defined above, but this is quite inefficient because of the branching on $t$. There is also sometimes an unexpected discontinuity at $t=\frac12$:
$$ \begin{gathered}
x = 0.9921611, \quad y = 4.0\\
x+\tfrac12(y-x) = 2.4960806, \qquad y-\tfrac12 (y-x) = 2.4960804.
\end{gathered} $$

*Does there exist an efficient simple formula that gives the linear interpolant with the standard mathematical properties?*

Comment: Closely related question and possibly useful answer on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907327/accurate-floating-point-linear-interpolation)

Comment: @njuffa I don't see any *conclusive* resolution there, but thanks for pointing to it. As a side note, they seemed to be using random numbers+exhaustive search for testing, but that can be a little unreliable—I think a good SMT solver like Z3 is a better way to go these days.

Comment: Few people are equipped to craft a formal mechanically-assisted proof. I am not aware of a mathematically *proven* solution in the literature (publications by S. Boldo would be one obvious place to look), so you might need to tackle a proof yourself if one is required. Pedro's suggested method showed no monotonicity failures in my testing; that's good enough for me. Note that a two-path solution need not be inefficient, depending on processor architecture compilers can predicate code or use select / conditional-move instructions to remove the branch.

Answer (score 3):

The following link might give some insight https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/linear-interpolation-past-present-and-future/

The suggested variant is:
`lerp_3(t, a, b) = fma(t, b, fnms(t, a, a))`

(fnms is fused negative multiply subract, so it can be reexpressed as `fma(-t, a, a)`, which should be equivalent from an accuracy, but not a performance, standpoint)

This is more accurate than ever including the $1-t$ explicitly, where I would expect most of the practical precision loss, so `fma(t, y, fma(-t, x, x))` in your variables.

I don't have a proof for the $x \leq y \leq z$ inequality, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand why this formula is appealing and looks better than what I have in the question, but I think in single precision this formula is not monotonic, counterexample: `(x,y,t1,t2) = (1.0f0, 3.2732666f0, 2.9802322f-8, 3.352763f-8)`, `z(t1) = 1.0000001f0 > z(t2) = 1.0f0`. I changed the question to make it explicit that this is undesirable (for obvious mathematical reasons).